# xcode error 'consecutive statements on a line must be separated by' when creating endpoint URL for REST API datatask

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, xcode7.3

I am a beginner, trying to code a POST datarequest to post a vote to the 'rating' field of a Drupalnode (so that users can rate movies). I have followed online guides, carefully copying the syntax, but in Xcode am receiving this error for  for this line:
        let movieEndpoint: String = https://www.examplesitename.com/film1
The red error message is "consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ';'
The error highlights the ':' after https, and suggests "fix it" with an ';' but changing it to https;www.examplesitename.com/film1 then brings up another red error 'expected expression' (and doesn't seem correct as it is a URL)

For context, below is my code, (which I hope will work to post my data request but haven't been able to check yet)

```
 let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let movieEndpoint: String = https://www.sitename.com/film1
    guard let movieURL = NSURL(string: movieEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    let movieUrlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: movieURL)
    movieUrlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(movieUrlRequest, completionHandler:{ _, _, _ in })

    let newRating = ["rating": 50, "userId": 1,]
    let jsonRating: NSData
    do {
        jsonRating = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(newRating, options: [])
        movieUrlRequest.HTTPBody = jsonRating
    } catch {
        print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
        return
    }
    movieUrlRequest.HTTPBody = jsonRating

    task.resume()

}
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Look at all those strings where you put quotes around them. Like "POST". Why not for your url string?

Comment: Yes that solves it!  Thank you so much Gnasher729

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to declare a String in Swift is to add " " around the string.

Fix your code like this:

```
let movieEndpoint: String = "https://www.sitename.com/film1"
```